# Looping script, redirect to file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, output

So I have this BASH script and what i want to do is, reach out to the servers. Check the used % of a directory. If it is higher than my set threshold (90) then print that server name to another file on the server where the script has been run from.

What it is doing is printing the first server name twice in to the file so it looks like

```
server1
server2
```

Here is my script ... I don't see why it would be going around in a loop to that first server twice

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERS="server1
server2"

for i in $SERVERS; do

        ssh $SERVERS "
        df -h | grep var | awk '{print \$4}' | sed 's/%//g' > /home/user/space.txt
        RESULTS=\$(grep -E "1[5-9]" /home/user/space.txt)
        THRESHOLD=90
        if [[ \$RESULTS -lt \$THRESHOLD ]]; then
        exit 1;
        elif [[ \$RESULTS -gt \$THRESHOLD ]]; then
        hostname;
        fi
        " >> /home/user/problem.txt
done
```

Comment: You want ssh $i

Comment: Your loop variable is `$i` but you say `ssh $SERVERS`. You want `ssh $i` so that first it does server1 then it does server2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVERS="server1
 server2"

for i in $SERVERS; do

    ssh "$i" "
    df -h | grep var | awk '{print \$4}' | sed 's/%//g' > /home/user/space.txt
    RESULTS=\$(grep -E "1[5-9]" /home/user/space.txt)
    THRESHOLD=90
    if [[ \$RESULTS -lt \$THRESHOLD ]]; then
    exit 1;
    elif [[ \$RESULTS -gt \$THRESHOLD ]]; then
    hostname;
fi
    " >> /home/user/problem.txt
done
```